# Vue.js 3 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, rest

So, I'm trying to fetch my laravel api and already run **php artisan serve**. After that the error came out and I'm looking to find solution here but I have no idea what's going on.

**The error shown in the console:**

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

**The API:**

```
{
  "message": "List trash and category order by time",
  "data": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "trash_id": 1,
  "category_id": 2,
  "created_at": "2022-01-01T12:41:43.000000Z",
  "updated_at": "2022-01-01T12:41:43.000000Z",
  "garbage": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Buku",
    "weight": 1,
    "created_at": "2022-01-01T12:41:19.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-01-01T12:41:19.000000Z"
   },
  "categories": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Kertas",
    "price": 1800
   }
 }]
}
```

**Index.vue script:**

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
import { onMounted, ref } from "vue";

export default {
  setup() {
    //   reactive state
    let all_trash = ref([]);

    onMounted(() => {
      // get data from api endpoint
      axios
        .get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/trash")
        .then((result) => {
          all_trash.value = result.data;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err.response);
        });
    });

    return {
      all_trash,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

**Index.vue HTML:**

```
<div v-for="(trash, index) in all_trash.data" :key="index">
      <div class="card rounded shadow mb-3">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="mx-3">
            <h5 class="mb-4">{{ trash.garbage.name }}</h5>
            <p>
              {{ trash.categories.name }}
              <span class="float-end">
                <button class="btn" style="color: red">Hapus</button>
              </span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a condition that not to render the loop until data is not set. The data from API end point is not available on the initial dom rendered and there is not data in `all_trash.data` hence the error. Just add a v-if on top of the div and hopefully it should work.

```
<div v-if=" all_trash.data"> 
 <div v-for="(trash, index) in all_trash.data" :key="index">
      <div class="card rounded shadow mb-3">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="mx-3">
            <h5 class="mb-4">{{ trash.garbage.name }}</h5>
            <p>
              {{ trash.categories.name }}
              <span class="float-end">
                <button class="btn" style="color: red">Hapus</button>
              </span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes sir, I got you, but the problem is there are some data in the API and it should appear without any error.

Comment: @FikriLazuardi the thing is API call is asynchronous so the data is not available on the first render and it can not find .data inside all_thrash which is causing the issue. Either add a check condition or alternatively initialize the ref like , let all_trash = ref({data:[]});